set http only and samesite flag for cookies in lighttpd
We are using lighttpd web server in our code base. It is that we need to add Samesite and HTTP ONLY flags for the cookie.
I have gone through many examples but all are related to PHP and some other language. We don't use PHP in our code. Is there anyway that I can get this? Can anything be done in the .conf file
We use C language in the backend.
Tried adding mod_usertrack in conf file which is present in /ete/lighttpd.conf

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie
https://wiki.lighttpd.net/mod_setenv
As already answered in https://redmine.lighttpd.net/issues/3252 you need to add the parameters to wherever your application produces Set-Cookie.
